# Create a string for a time variable

Tags: c#, string

I have a text box which I want to show a string variable in, like `ddd:dd:dd`. This variable shows time, and I want to create it according to other variable.

My code is:

```
 int s = 12; // For example
 int r = 8; // For example
 string result =  "000" + r / s + ":"; // Day part
 result += "00" + (r - (r  / s) * (s / 60))+ ":"; // Hour part
 result += "00" + (r - (r  / s) * (s % 60)); // Minute part
 return result;
```

I want to have the final variable as mentioned in the first line. What should I do? For example, I don't want to have `2:4:3`. Instead, I want to have `002:04:03`.

Comment: Do you have a `DateTime` already in somewhere? If not, you can use `String.PadLeft()` method to put `0` left side of your strings.

Comment: @SonerGönül: no I dont

Comment: I would recommend using either a `DateTime` or a `TimeSpan`, depending on what your numbers actually mean, simply in order to keep the meaning clear. After that, the formatting is no different, but reading, explaining and understanding the code will be easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [**this**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can use these formattings:

```
 int s = 12; // for example
 int r = 8; // for example

 result = string.Format("{0:000}:{1:00}:{2:00}", 
                        r / s, 
                        (r - (r / s) * (s / 60)), 
                        (r - (r / s) * (s % 60)));
```

---

```
  result = string.Format("{0:D3}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", 
                    r / s, 
                    (r - (r / s) * (s / 60)), 
                    (r - (r / s) * (s % 60)));
```

Comment: Isn't there an extra zero in each parameter in the format string? OP wants 3-2-2, not 4-3-3.